# Transferring blend projects between pcs

Tags: export, import, linked-data

Ive started a project on my pc that I would like to finish on my laptop. The project has active (not applied) modifiers and several non parented pieces.

What would be the best method of transfer ?

Comment: "*The project has active (not applied) modifiers and several non parented pieces.*" How is this relevant to the transferral process? Am I misunderstanding something in your question?

Comment: essentially the blend file is just a text-file (yes, some other file types as well) but never a computer specific file. That's why every computer which Blender supports, can read that blend file.

Comment: you could do *File > External Data > Pack Resources* and then copy/paste the blend file to your laptop and then do *File > External Data > Unpack Resources*. So you can still keep your external data separate.

Comment: This sounds as if you are asking for ways to transfer one file from one machine to the other. In which way is this a specific Blender question? Depending on the size of the project you can do things like put everything on a USB stick, either zipped or just as it is, or email a zip file, or upload everything on Google Drive and download it from there etc... As Duarte said, what have the modifiers and non-parented pieces to do with that, are you saving them somehow separately?

Answer (score 0):

You could try emailing the respective file to your laptop and then downloading it. If you have OneDrive, you could enable it on both computers and transfer the file through your parent account. Or you could download it to a external hard drive and upload it to your laptop.